# JTextPane set with HTMLEditorkit not honouring text-align style when used with <pre> tag

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

The code snippet below when run wont display any text in JTextPane.
The text-align style in pre tag not at all honoured. If text-align style is removed OR if it is set to 'left', the text is displayed in JTextPane. We are using 'pre' tag to maintain the white spaces and tab indentation.

My requirements are :

1) Should be able to see the text in center/right align fashion.

2) White spaces and tab in the text string need to displayed as it is on JTextPane.

Any help would be most appreciated.!!

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class TestHTML {
public static void main(String[] args){
    javax.swing.JTextPane editor = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    editor.setEditorKit(new javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit());
    String htmlText = "<html><head></head><body>" +
            "<pre style='text-align:center;color:blue;'>   " +
            "Hello   Spaced            World       !!!</pre>" +
            "</body></html>";
    editor.setText(htmlText);

    Document doc = editor.getDocument();
    try {
        System.out.println(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    javax.swing.JFrame f = new javax.swing.JFrame("HTML Editor");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(editor);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the `pre` element was originally intended to be left aligned (for left to right text), and that is why Swing is ignoring the request.  Why not try putting it as `code` inside a `div` instead?  Vis:

[image: Test HTML]

```
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestHTML {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
        editor.setContentType("text/html");
        String htmlText = "<html><head></head><body>" +
            "<div style='text-align: center;'>" +
            "<code style='color:blue;'>   " +
            "Hello   SpacedWorld   !!!</code>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</body></html>";
        editor.setText(htmlText);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("HTML Editor");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(editor);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

I just realized that the spaces between words were being compacted to 1.  Replace each one with `&nbsp;` to fix that.

Comment: Putting the text as **code** inside a div, does honor alignment but tabs are ignored. The problem is, text would be randomly passed in to this method and we are suppose to decorate it with HTML tags and set it on JTextPane. Tabs can be handled with **&nbsp;** but text may also contain new lines ('\n') as well. How to preserve them when ready to set the text on JTextPane ?

Comment: How are tabs *supposed* to be handled in centered text?  It would seem they are redundant in that case.  As for new lines, it will be necessary to break the text into separate `div` elements.